# How do I remove the upload button but keep the label?

Tags: html, file, button, upload, label

I'm trying to make it so when you click a certain part of the page, the user can upload a file. Right now, i've made it so the button's opacity is 0, but the label also disappears. I just want the label to be there but the button to be gone.

Basic code: http://pastebin.com/gWYVNPxK

Comment: Can you provide us with the code you have so far?

Comment: Here you are: http://pastebin.com/gWYVNPxK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using `display` instead of `opacity`, and a little bit of jQuery to make the text trigger the now-hidden button:

> JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Hybridx24/qou099nj/

Comment: Thank you, but when I try to add an attachment using your code, the name of my file doesn't appear. Do you know how to get the value of the button?

Comment: Check my link again, I modified it a little bit more to output the filename as well :)

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you again!!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! If this was the correct answer don't forget to press the checkmark on the left of my answer + upvote in case anyone else stumbles in, as it will help them find the quickest solution.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `<button onclick=".."`/> you can have `<div onclick="..">` or `<span onclick="..">` where span/div will represent the clickable part of the page

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#_uploadText').on('click', function() {
  $('#_inputFile').click();
})

$('#_inputFile').on('change', function() {
 var value = $("#_inputFile").val();
 $("#_fileName").html(value);
})
```

```css
input {
 display: none
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2">
 <input id="_inputFile" type="file" class="form-control">
 <small id="_uploadText"> Click or Drag an Attachment </small>
  <br>
  <span id="_fileName"></span>
```

use extra jquery on change for display value of input file